# Broadcast comparison between two different sized vectors

Tags: python, numpy

So I have a vector 1x4 *cumpr*:

```
In [119]:

cumpr
Out[119]:
array([ 0.30769231,  0.38461538,  0.53846154,  1.        ])
```

and a 1x10 vector *r*:

```
In [120]:

r
Out[120]:
array([ 0.90737839,  0.05419125,  0.14056591,  0.73179618,  0.34456476,
        0.27682039,  0.74046728,  0.93973422,  0.67263953,  0.44141488])
```

For every element in *r* I want to do the following (for example, for the first element in *r*):

```
In [86]:

np.nonzero(cumpr > r[0])[0][0]
Out[86]:
3
```

i.e., return the index of the first element in *cumpr* where that element is bigger than *r[0]*.

But is there a way to do this for all elements in *r* without looping? If I try broadcasting

```
cumpr > r
```

I just get an error.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can simply use `np.searchsorted`:

```
>>> np.searchsorted(cumpr, r)
array([3, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 2])
```

Sanity check:

```
>>> ix = np.searchsorted(cumpr, r)
>>> cumpr[ix]
array([ 1.        ,  0.30769231,  0.30769231,  1.        ,  0.38461538,
        0.30769231,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.53846154])
>>> cumpr[ix] >= r
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Note though that you *don't* have "a vector 1x4" and "a 1x10 vector"; you have two *one-dimensional arrays*, of shape `(4,)` and `(10,)`.  This is important for understanding the broadcasting version:

```
>>> (cumpr > r[:,None]).argmax(1)
array([3, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 2])
```

which builds an intermediate array by adding a single-element axis.